# Change the color of ImageButton in a RecyclerView using an interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-imagebutton

This question is related to my previous question in 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858440/how-to-change-the-color-of-vector-assigned-to-imagebutton-in-a-recyclerview).

I have a `RecyclerView` which shows several (8) `CardView`s. Inside each `CardView`, there are several elements like `TextView`, `ImageButton`, etc. What I want to do is change the color of Vector (.xml) assigned to the `ImageButton` using the `OnClickListener` of the same button.

I'm using an interface to communicate between Adapter class (RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter) and the fragment.

```
public interface RvItemClickListener {
    void cardClick(View view, int position);
    void alarmClick(View view,int position);
}
```

In Adapter class:

```
public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Person> persons;
RvItemClickListener rvItemClickListener;
private Context mContext;

public RvAdapter(Context context,List<Person> persons) {
    this.mContext=context;
    this.persons=persons;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_content,parent,false);
    ViewHolder vh=new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ViewHolder mHolder=holder;
    mHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(position).name);
    mHolder.personAge.setText( persons.get(position).age);
}   

public void adapterSetClickListener(RvItemClickListener rvItemClickListener){
    this.rvItemClickListener=rvItemClickListener;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    CardView cvCard;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageButton alarmImageButton;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cvCard=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_card);
        personName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_person_name);
        personAge=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_person_age);
        alarmImageButton=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_image_button);

        cvCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        alarmImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.cv_card:
                if(rvItemClickListener!=null)
                    rvItemClickListener.cardClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            case R.id.alarm_image_button:
                if(rvItemClickListener!=null)
                    rvItemClickListener.alarmClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my Fragment class:

```
public class Main_fragment extends Fragment implements RvItemClickListener{
  private RvAdapter myRecyclerAdaper;
  ImageButton alarmImageButton;
  private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> clickedItems;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     myRecyclerAdaper.adapterSetClickListener(this);
     clickedItems=new HashMap<>();
  }

  @Override
public void cardClick(View view, int position) {
    //openinig a new fragment.....this works fine
    getDataToBundle(view,position);
    nextFragmentInstance.setTargetFragment(this,0);
    nextFragmentInstance.setArguments(detailsToPass);
    this.getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_main,newFragmentInstance,"tag")
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

 @Override
 public void alarmClick(View view, int position) {
    //toast to make sure wheather the click event identify the position... works fine 
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   //changing the color of ImageButton vector using an instance of it
    alarmImageButton=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_image_button);
    if(!clickedItems.containsKey(position)) {
        alarmImageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        clickedItems.put(position, true);
    }else{
        alarmImageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0,0,0,0));
        clickedItems.remove(position);
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't given the full code of Fragment class. If anyone wants I can update the code.

However the question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858440/how-to-change-the-color-of-vector-assigned-to-imagebutton-in-a-recyclerview). Only difference is this time I'm using an interface instead of `onBindViewHolder()` for click events. 
When I clicked on a `ImageButton`, its vector color is changed along with another `ImageButton`'s vector. I tried to solve this as in the link I gave. However I failed.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling into the `Fragment`? As i see you're only changing the color of the buttons, which you could simply do from the `Adapter`.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim  I have a main fragment in my activity. My purpose is to load another fragment when Cardview is clicked and set alarm when the Imagebutton is clicked. By changing colors  I'm trying to understand how click events work in Recyclerview. Yes, I achieved it in Adapter with your help. Here I just tried to do the same thing using an Interface. Just for my knowledge.

Comment: @TofferJ  Thanks for the edit.